# Javascript replace code of function

Tags: javascript, replace

I am making a bookmarklet and need to change some code inside a page. For example, after page loaded it creates a function which is used 'onclick'. I need to replace a code inside a variable of this function. For example here is a function:

```
function openNewWindow(){
    newWindow = window.open('http://www.example.org','params','width=200,height=200,resizable=0');
```

And I need to change this code into this:

```
function openNewWindow(){
    newWindow = window.open('http://www.example.org','params','_blank');
```

How can I do it, taking in account, that the function is loaded by ajax?

Comment: *the function is loaded by ajax* - are you loading a function declaration content by ajax?

Comment: ajax.php loads a part of code after it calculates a data.

Comment: if that content is generated by backend side, then make replacement on backend and let front-end get a prepared content

Comment: But if I have only frontend access? It's a bookmarklet that clicks on popup in a new tab, instead of new window.

Comment: let's comprehend things as they are: are you working with some text and just trying to replace one substring to another ?

Comment: No, I'm working with a page that has some code. On click an href calls a function. The function comes from ajax.php few seconds after the page is loaded. I need to replace a part of the code, to modify the action of the function.

Comment: show `ajax.php` content and function call code

Comment: I can't show ajax.php. Here is how the function called: ``<a onclick="openNewWindow()"``

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be overwritting by being asigned a new refrence, if you only have access to the front end of the code after the fact. You can replace `openNewWindow` with a new function;

```
openNewWindow = function () {
    newWindow = window.open('http://www.example.org','params','_blank'); 
}
```

However replacing functions that come from third parties are not recomended in a lot of cases because it can produce unexpected results.

Comment: But if I need to reaplce only a part of function's code, because the rest of the code might be random.

Comment: You can compose a new function to call your code and then the original functions code. Only replacing part of the code is not reccomended to keep doing something the safe way (avoiding `function.toString()` and `eval`).

Comment: But I can use ``var ev = window[fnstring];`` instead of eval?

Comment: Unsure how that would solve your issue. That would access a global object with the value of `fnstring`.